# Add/copy row below for each value > 0

Tags: excel, vba

So I use Excel VBA to build easy macro's, but now its getting a little bit too complex for me. I want to copy a row each time a certain value appears in column F till J. So, if column F row 2 has a cell value > 0, than the entire row needs to be copied below exept for the cell values in column G till J. If column G row 2 also has a cell value > 0, then the entire row needs to be copied again exept for the cell values of column F, H till J. The picture below shows what I really wanna achieve.

[image: Example]

After days of trial and error with different codes, I see that the following vba code inserts blank rows, without copying the row above it.

```
 Sub Add_Rows()
  Dim r As Long

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  For r = Range("F:G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 4 Step -1
    If Cells(r, "f:G").Value > 0 Then Rows(r + 1).Resize(Cells(r, "G").Value).Insert
  Next r
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

How do I need to adjust this code in order to get it exactly as the example?

Comment: Do you not get any errors?  This line, `Range("F:G" & Rows.Count)`, isn't how you'd use a range. You at least want to do `Range("F1:G" & rows.Count)`, but even then I highly doubt you want to loop through every single row in the worksheet?

Comment: @BruceWayne well OP is using `.End(xlUp).Row` but your point about the range notation still stands.

Comment: `Cells(r, "f:")` - get rid of that colon.

Comment: It does loop through every single row. Very disturbing, and it just adds blank rows. So Im really struggle in finding out how this work. Tomorrow evening this assignment is due, let hope for the best :) !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want your program to needlessly search every single row in the workbook. You should instead have to search until it reaches the last row that has value. I have already written a function that looks for the last row with a value in a given sheet. It looks like this:

```
'Returns the last row in the specified sheet containing a value
Function returnLastRow(ByVal sheetName As String, countCol As Integer) As Long
    With Sheets(sheetName)
        returnLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, countCol).End(xlUp).row
    End With
End Function
```

The function is passed the sheet name and column that you want it to search in and returns the last row that has a value. Example function call that looks in the first column of a worksheet called "work" and returns the last row that contains a value:

```
bottomRow = returnLastRow("work", 1)
```

Now we can pass the bottomRow variable to the Add_Rows() subroutine which it can use to narrow down the range that it's going to operate on. When looping through a dynamic range, it's best to use the [Range.cells() property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.cells) because we can numerically refer to the rows and columns. Here's how I would modify your subroutine:

```
Sub Add_Rows(ByVal sheetName As String, bottomRow As Long)
    With Sheets(sheetName)
        For ctr = 1 To bottomRow
            If (.Cells(ctr, 10).Value > 0) Then
                'insert a blank row
                .Rows(ctr + 1 & ":" & ctr + 1).Insert
                '+1 to bottomRow since we've added a new row.
                bottomRow = bottomRow + 1
                'Copy information from ctr row
                .Range(.Cells(ctr, 1), .Cells(ctr, 5)).Copy
                'Add to new row
                .Range(.Cells(ctr + 1, 1), .Cells(ctr + 1, 5)).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
            End If
        Next ctr
    End With
End Sub
```